# Communicating between a running Ruby and Java program

Tags: java, ruby, request, siri, bridge

I want to run a Java program and a Ruby program both all the time, and if needed I want both to communicate with each other, without having one program to call the other each time it's needed (like JRuby is doing as far as I could figure it out).

I need something like HTTP requests or similar, where I could call a method in the Java program with the parameters passed by the Ruby script.

---

The concrete scenario is the following: I have a [Siri-Proxy](https://github.com/plamoni/SiriProxy) running on my server. When my plugin recognizes some specified command, it has to communicate with some Middleware written in Java (what needs to be passed to the Middleware is the room, the element to handle and the action to do).

That way, the Middleware would be able to handle the request and be modular regarding more actions like writing the params into a database or interact with some home control software.

Comment: I think this question is too broad for Stack Overflow. There are a lot of ways to do this.

Comment: Naming some would be a great help (I mentioned also concretely HTTP requests, so this would be a good hook for help advices..)

Comment: If you don't know about the various IPC protocols already, I'm pretty sure you're not quite ready to write something because you don't know how to pick the right one for your needs. And, you haven't given us any information useful for us to really make a good recommendation. Grabbing something from the air I'd say you should look at SOAP or REST, which are supported by Java and Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, what exactly you are asking for, but [Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (IPC) is—as [already stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655510/communicating-between-a-running-ruby-and-java-program#comment23958718_16655510)—a very broad field.

Possible solutions range from simple writing to/reading from a shared file, over sockets and embedded webservers to message queue middleware. Depending on your case, a seperate AMQP or Redis server handling the communication might be overkill. A file exchange on the other hand is quite error prone when not done carefully.

You could also [easily](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html) implement an HTTP server in your Ruby program, to which Java app submits requests to get a one-way communication set up.

If you need a more precise answer, please also provide more information. What *exactly* is your goal? Is performance an issue? Should it be just for testing purposes? What kind of data do you want to transfer?

Comment: IPC is already a good headword for the starting, thanks! :) Btw. I described my concrete use case in my question.